# Processor utilization percentage for multiple, multicore processors 

Tags: windows, task-manager, performance-monitor

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine with two processors:

```
Intel Xeon CPU E5630 @2.53Ghz, 2533Mhz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors 

Intel Xeon CPU E5630 @2.53Ghz, 2533Mhz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors
```

which show up as 16 instances on the perfmon/task manager.

The overall processor time(total) shows 20% but 2 individual processor instances show above 80%. How do I interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a program/process that is only coded to use 2 cores, and is using them fairly intensely. The rest of the cores are close to idle. The 20% is a percentage of all 16 cores.